# Using NaCl/libsodium crypto in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, cryptography, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I try to find out, what's the right way to use the NaCl library in Objective-C. Keygeneration seems easy:

```
- (void) generateKeypair {
    unsigned char pk[crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    unsigned char sk[crypto_box_SECRETKEYBYTES];

    sodium_init();
    crypto_box_keypair(pk,sk);
    self.publicKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)pk
                                            length:sizeof(unsigned char)*crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    self.sekretKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)sk
                                            length:sizeof(unsigned char)*crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
}
```

That was easy. But with the `crypto_box(c,m,mlen,n,pk,sk)` function I get mixed up with padding, `ZEROBYTES` and how to manage object ownership. How to build a simple Wrapper for `crypto_box(c,m,mlen,n,pk,sk)` and friends?

Comment: You are requesting code, without showing what you tried yourself. But as it is only one method I guess we can turn a blind eye.

Comment: Sure. I think C is not the language to try mixing pointers and casts until it compiles. PErhaps I just don't have the intellectual tools for researching it myself. In a dynamic language with introspection I would have experimented with the code until it returned something. But in C with crypto code I feel this is the wrong approach ....

Comment: This is not an easy question for me to answer unfortunately, I have voted up but that's about all I can do. You may want to put a bounty on it if you want it resolved.

Comment: You should drop the `cryptography` and `libsodium` tags. This is simply Objective C classes and memory management design questions; and not NaCL library. Use the spare tag to bring in more Objective C folks with the `iPhone` tag. With that said, you might see some votes to close because your design questions are too high level.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [Sodium-Objc](https://github.com/Tabbedout/SodiumObjc). These bindings haven't been updated for a while, but they remain pretty good, and make it really easy to use `crypto_box` in Objective-C.

Another option is [Swift-Sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium), that is more complete. It was written in Swift, but calling Objective-C from Swift should be easy enough.

But if you want to go low-level and directly call the C functions, you actually don't have to worry about padding. Just use the [easy interface](http://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption.html): `crypto_box_easy()` and `crypto_box_open_easy()`.

`crypto_box_easy()` puts the authenticator (`crypto_box_MACBYTES` bytes long) immediately followed by the encrypted message. No extra padding is required. And `crypto_box_open_easy()` decrypts the message without requiring extra padding or having to move bytes around.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote crypto_secretbox in this lib and I do the padding as defined in the docs: https://github.com/gabriel/NACL/blob/master/NACL/NASecretBox.m

It might help if the padding setup is the same for crypto_box.